# Set Windows Phone 8 App as default for file extensions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to register my Windows Phone 8 App, as the default app for opening specific files (for example all files, that end with `*.test`).

So my question is: how do i register my app to Windows Phone 8, so that it opens my app when a user want's to open a `*.test`-file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You register your application in the app manifest. For detailed instructions, read [Registering for a file association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Fileassociations) on MSDN.